# Boundedness of Surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, surfaces

GIven an equation such as $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dxy+exz+fyz=g$ where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g\in \mathbb R$, How can we tell if the surface described is a bounded one without explicitly plotting a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface is bounded iff the eigenvalues of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
a   & d/2 & e/2 \\
d/2 & b   & f/2 \\
e/2 & f/2 & c \\
\end{pmatrix}$ have the same sign.

One way to show this is to compute the extrema of function $$(x,y,z)\mapsto x^2+y^2+z^2$$ restricted to the surface. You can do this using Lagrange multipliers very easily.

Alternatively, it is not difficult to see that there is a linear change of variables which takes your function to one of the form $$\alpha X^2+\beta Y^2+\gamma Z^2$$ for which the question is very easy.

Answer (score 2):

With $$ g > 0:  $$
It is bounded if and only if $$ a > 0 $$ and $$ 4 ab - d^2 > 0  $$ and $$ 4 abc + def - a f^2 - b e^2 - c d^2 > 0.  $$

This is called [Sylvester's Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion). See also [TWEETY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweety). And [SYLVESTER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_%28Looney_Tunes%29).

Comment: Haha! Nice associations...!